# GRAPH_EDGES not working and documentation not helping

Tags: arangodb

Ok so I am posting here because ArangoDB documentation is not helping me. I am moving from 2.5.7 to latest ArangoDB. I was using the GRAPH_EDGES in one of the query and it is not working anymore. I followed https://github.com/arangodb/docs/blob/28b266f143232beb17e5c35cd545d4f3909a1815/3.6/cookbook/aql-migrating-graph-functions-to3.md but this is not correct. At one place it says not to use @graphName but then it keep showing the use of it.
My Query is as following:

```
{"query":"for P in GRAPH_EDGES(@graph, @example, {edgeCollectionRestriction:\"myEdgeCollection\"}) RETURN P","bindVars":{"example":{"signature":"sig1"}, "graph" : "GRAPH2"}}
```

I tried the following query change and it returns empty result:

```
{"query":"for P in ANY @startId myEdgeCollection  RETURN P","bindVars":{"startId":{"signature":"sig1"}}}
```

Can somebody help.

Comment: Did the answer work for you? if yes, can you mark it 'accepted'? If not, whats missing?

Comment: I will check it this week.

Answer (score 1):

The use of graphName depends on the case. The docu doesn't tell you to never use it anymore.

In your case you have to replace `P` with `v, e`. You can find more information about the syntax [here](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/graphs/traversals/#syntax).

Then your code should look like follow:

```
{"query":"for v, e in ANY @startId myEdgeCollection RETURN e","bindVars":{"startId":{"signature":"sig1"}}}
```